# Maven POM.xml problem - Unknown error at top line ( <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> )

Tags: spring-boot, pom.xml

I am setting up a project in STS with Spring starter project and added required dependencies like spring security and JSP. But the top line of pom file throwing an error as Unknown

Can anybody help me out to resolve this?

I am using STS 4

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>RememberMeApp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>RememberMeApp</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-mavenplugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Usually this should work without any error

Comment: There is supposed to be an error icon in front of the first line, you can move your cursor on it to view the error message in STS.

Comment: Yes, there is a cross error icon but when cursor moves over it is not showing any error message

Answer (score 14):

This is the latest surprise [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=547340) when using with Spring Boot 2.1.5 due to Spring Boot 2.1.5 upgrade `maven-jar-plugin` to 3.1.2

The workaround is to downgrade it to the previous version by adding the following to `pom.xml` :

```
<properties>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.1</maven-jar-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: Thank you Ken Chan. It has worked fine and the error resolved

Comment: @Sunil, Glad to hear . So consider to accept my answers or give me a vote up  

Answer (score 0):

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide the answer, it would be much more useful if the purpose of the code is explained along with the reason it answers the original question.